# Adjoint of a linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be an inner product space. We define a linear transformation T as $T(\alpha)=(\alpha|\beta)\gamma$, where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are fixed. Then show that this operator has an adjoint. Find it explicitly.

Edit: Here is what I tried. Suppose T has an adjoint. Then $(T(a)|b)=(a|T^*(b)) \; \implies \; ((a|\beta)\gamma|b)=(a|T^*b)$. This implies $(\gamma|(\beta|a)b)=(a|T^*b)$. How do I proceed from here.

Comment: 1) What have you tried so far? 2) Please, specify clearly your hypothesis.

Comment: Definition of T is that inner Product.. <\alpha,\beta>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\def\innp#1#2{(#1\mid#2)}$I'll assume your inner product space is over the reals.

Suppose $T$ has an adjoint $T^*$, that is,
$$
\innp{x}{T(y)}=\innp{T^*(x)}{y}
$$
for all $x,y\in V$. Then
$$
\innp{T^*(x)}{y}=\innp{x}{T(y)}=
\innp{x}{\innp{y}{\beta}\gamma}=
\innp{y}{\beta}\innp{x}{\gamma}=
\innp{y}{\innp{x}{\gamma}\beta}=
\innp{\innp{x}{\gamma}\beta}{y}
$$
which means $T^*(x)=\innp{x}{\gamma}\beta$.

Now, try proving that this map is the one you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks bro! That was awesome.